# Qt's model/view architecture

Tags: qt, linq-to-sql, qtsql

After making connection with the  database , I have written the following code, but after execution view's inner cells are empty. WHy?

```
enum {
        name = 0,
        clas = 1,
        launched = 2
    };

      QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel;
       model->setTable("ships");
       model->setSort(name, Qt::AscendingOrder);
       model->setHeaderData(name, Qt::Horizontal, "Name");
       model->setHeaderData(clas, Qt::Horizontal, "class");
       model->setHeaderData(launched, Qt::Horizontal, "launched");

       model->select();   

     QTableView *  view = new QTableView;   

           view->setModel(model);
           view->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
           view->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
           view->resizeColumnsToContents();
           view->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
           QHeaderView *header = view->horizontalHeader();
           header->setStretchLastSection(true);
           view->show();
```

Comment: Show the code where you are connecting to database.

Comment: QString servername="DESKTOP-5ML5OT3";
    QString dbname="Student";
    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setConnectOptions();
    QString dsn=QString("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;").arg(servername).arg(dbname);
     db.setDatabaseName(dsn);

    db.open();

Comment: @Katrin Please edit the question to address the deficiencies indicated in the comments. A proper response to a comment, in most cases, is to edit the question, not add a comment.