# View doesn't display data from the model

Tags: qt, linq-to-sql, qsqltablemodel

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

After making connection, I tried this code , but it doesn't display any data

```
   QSqlTableModel *model=new QSqlTableModel; 
   model->setTable("tamp");
   model->select();
   QTableView *view = new QTableView;
   view->setModel(model);
   view->show();
   db.close();
   return a.exec()
}
```

Comment: The code that you show us would crash (since you don't allocate a model), so it's hard to say anything at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt's model/view architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078500/qts-model-view-architecture)

Comment: You should not be calling `db.close()` after `view->show()`. `QSqlTableModel` requires the database connection to be open while it is being used (e.g. for editing to work).